# ServiceStack api/auth/credentials returns 404 on frontend migration

Tags: c#, servicestack, credentials

I'm changing my frontend to React, so I started a new project with VS2015. I already configured ServiceStack with my old API services. Everything works fine except by one: api/auth/credentials.

I get a 404 when I try to send a POST.

My `Configure` has:

```
public MyApphost() : base("My web services", typeof(MyApphost).Assembly) {}
```

and:

(In a previous call to Plugins)

```
IoC.Container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(Dvtrck.Configuration.Manager.Current.Dsn, Dvtrck.Services.OrmLiteDialects.PostgreSQLDialectProviderLowerCase.Instance));
```

... (Some code and)

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() =>
    new UserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new CustomAuthProvider(), // CustomAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
    }));
```

And my web.config has:

```
<location path="api">
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <!-- ServiceStack: Required for IIS7 -->
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I already checked similar questions but my case is different. Even I had no errors when adds `AuthFeature`. I don't get why works fine in my old project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also [need to configure](http://docs.servicestack.net/servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework):

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { HandlerFactoryPath = "api" });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. (And added `routes.IgnoreRoute ("api/{*pathInfo}");` to `RegisterRoutes`)